# Which out of the following is correct?

Tags: grammar

1. The data that I get with my mobile plan is little
2. The data that I get with my mobile plan is less
3. The data that I get with my mobile plan is limited to use

Comment: #2 would only make sense if the answer to *Less than **what**?* is contextually obvious. The best I can come up with would be *The data that I get with my mobile plan is **limited***. We don't say things like *You get little / big / much / data with this plan* (only ***...very little** data, **...a lot of** data*; some kind of quantifier is usually needed for idiomacy).

Comment: Is this sentence right?   The data that I get with my mobile plan is just limited to use.

Comment: I get ***limited data*** with my mobile phone. I get less data than you do. More data, less data are comparatives.

Comment: Not a perfect sentence, but close enough for government work: **The amount of data that I get with my mobile plan is not a lot**.